# Can't open Android App twice

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, apk

This is my first stackoverflow question, so if I'm doing things wrong please correct me.

I've got a problem with my android app. I'm working on a Android Eclipse project and testing it by letting Eclipse run the apk file on my phone(Samsung Galaxy S3). This works perfectly fine:

- [2014-12-18 12:42:22 - Urly De Uil] Uploading Urly De Uil.apk onto device '4df17046685e7ff1'
- [2014-12-18 12:42:22 - Urly De Uil] Installing Urly De Uil.apk...
- [2014-12-18 12:42:29 - Urly De Uil] Success!

The problem however is that when I close the app, on my phone, and try to reopen it, my phone tells me the application is not installed. So my question is as follows: are there some general problems which can cause this to happen? Or does anybody recognize this specific problem?

Additional Info:

- I don't have my apk signed.
- When I started the Eclipse Project it did install and was able to reopen it after closing, but I think since I added a SqLite Database this problem occured.
- I also tried to install the apk file by placing it on my phone and install it from download folder, but got the same problem.

I hope someone can help!

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the `adb logcat` log.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but im not sure what part of logcat to look at(I forgot to mention im not an experienced Android Developer). What part of logcat are you looking for? I got a whole bunch of these errors.
12-18 13:31:38.710: E/installd(1937): system dir 0 : /system/app/
12-18 13:31:38.715: E/installd(1937): system dir 0 : /system/app/
12-18 13:31:38.725: E/installd(1937): system dir 0 : /system/app/
12-18 13:31:38.730: E/installd(1937): system dir 0 : /system/app/
12-18 13:31:38.740: E/installd(1937): system dir 0 : /system/app/

Comment: _What part of logcat?_ You never know in advance. You just read the whole stuff and at some point you see an error message (one among many). You may search the log file for the beginning of your package name or some other relevant word.